# Report Filters filtering only by created date

Tags: reporting, filters, custom-reports

I want to Create some reports on Account object and i see as filter Created Date as well as to choose to filter between other date fields (find screenshot). I cannot lock this field or exclude it from filters as i see... How could i make it possible for the user that runs this report to be able to filter ONLY with Created Date and not with other dates?[image: Reports screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_builder_filtering.htm&type=5

This filter is included in every report by default and can't be removed, locked, or restricted in terms of what's available to select. It'll always display all date fields of the object in the filter for you to select. You only have the ability to choose which field to select (in your case, CreatedDate).

Comment: Thanks for your response! That's exactly what i was just reading when you answered me the question! but hoped there was a solution to that!

Comment: It might be useful to create an idea for allowing some sort of customization on these filters (to lock for instance). I didn't see an existing one, although I didn't look too hard.

Comment: Thanks, Kris :)